# How to use discord python bot with proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, discord, discord.py

Need to use discord bot with proxy (https or socks). 
For example, proxy is: 192.168.1.1:3125 and proxy autorisation is: proxy_login:proxy_pass

I already try with this example: [how to connect a discord bot through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158310/how-to-connect-a-discord-bot-through-proxy) but it can't.

```
client = discord.Client(proxy=USER_PROXY, proxy_auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth(USER_PROXY_LOGIN, USER_PROXY_PASS))
```

Answer (score 4):

The below is for an old version of discord.py, for modern versions refer to Xiao Tan's answer

---

You need to create a [`aiohttp.ProxyConnector`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v1.0.0/client_reference.html#proxyconnector) and pass that as the `connector` to your `Client`:

```
from aiohttp import ProxyConnector, BasicAuth

basic_auth = BasicAuth(USER_PROXY_LOGIN, USER_PROXY_PASS)
connector = ProxyConnector(USER_PROXY, proxy_auth=basic_auth)

cient = discord.Client(connector=connector)
```

As the question you linked notes, discord.py does not support HTTP proxies, only HTTPS proxies.

Comment: in aiohttp this code:  `def update_proxy(self, proxy, proxy_auth):
        if proxy and not proxy.startswith('http://'):
            raise ValueError("Only http proxies are supported")
        if proxy_auth and not isinstance(proxy_auth, helpers.BasicAuth):
            raise ValueError("proxy_auth must be None or BasicAuth() tuple")
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.proxy_auth = proxy_auth` so it doesn't work with https?

Comment: @СергейЖиренкин What version of discord.py and aiohttp are you using?

Comment: discord - 0.16.12   aiohttp - 1.0.5  python 3.6

Comment: Hi the link has been changed to glqiwiapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_features/proxy.html , sadly it didn't work for me I still got the error "Cannot connect to host discord.com:443" but Xiao Tan's solution works.

Answer (score 2):

For the newest version 1.7.3, There is a `proxy` parameter on `Client` class's constructor

all you need is:

```py
client = discord.Client(proxy="http://localhost:7890")
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client

Comment: ProxyConnector doesn't work for me but your works! Thanks.