# Use discord.py with a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, discord.py

I want to log in my discord bot using a proxy due to internet limitations. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355342/how-to-use-discord-python-bot-with-proxy) article, and tried to follow it but I can't find `connector` as a valid kwarg in the bot constructor.

So how could I connect over a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It's not listed in [`Bot`'s documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0/ext/commands/api.html#bot) because [`Bot` is just a subclass of `Client`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/f308f34db1b1c24178fbdb1756838064cd9e4348/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L945) and [just passes any extra `**options` to `Client`'s constructor](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/f308f34db1b1c24178fbdb1756838064cd9e4348/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L99), so you should just be able to pass `connector=<your connector>` to the `Bot` constructor.

Comment: I've tried something like that, but can't figure it out as there's barely any documentation on it.